# CDF of a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, random-variable

Define $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be two positive and independent random variables, for which the pdf (probability density function) is the same and is given as:
$f(y) = \beta \exp\left(- \beta y\right),\beta>0$.
Suppose that time is slotted, and $t$ ($=0,1,2,...$) is the time index. $Y_1$ is associated with time $t$ and $Y_2$ with time $t+1$.
For $a,b,c>0$, $a>1$ and $c=\frac{\log(a)}{b}$, we define $p(s)$ to be some error probability that is a function of $s$, which is given as follows
\begin{equation}
p(s) = \begin{cases}  a \exp\left( - b s \right),    & \text{for $s \ge c$}    \\ 1,  & \text{for $0 < s < c $}    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
At time $t$, $s=y_1$. And at time $t+1$, $s=y_1+y_2$.
Let $E_1$ represent the event of having an error at time $t$; the corresponding probability is $p(y_1)$. Also, define $E_2$ to be the event that there is an error at time $t+1$; the corresponding probability is $p(y_1+y_2)$. For $E_2$ to happen (at $t+1$), a necessary condition is that $E_1$ happens (at $t$).

Let $E$ be the event that there is an error at time $t$ and $t+1$. So we have $\mathbb{P}\{ E \}= \mathbb{P}\{ E_1, E_2 \}= \mathbb{P}\{ E_1 \} \mathbb{P}\{ E_2 \mid E_1 \} = p(y_1) p(y_1+y_2)$. So if the realisations $y_1$ and $y_2$ of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are known, the (global) error probability is $p(y_1) p(y_1+y_2)$.

I am interested in the case where at $t$ and $t+1$ the realisations of, respectively, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not known. Let $Z= p(Y_1) p(Y_1+Y_2)$.
So in this case I want to derive the expected value of $Z$. I also want to derive the CCDF (or CDF) of $Z$.

Here is my first attempt of a solution
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E} \left\{Z\right\} &=&\int_0^\infty  \int_0^\infty  p(y_1) p(y_1+y_2) \,  f(y_1) f(y_2) \,dy_1 dy_2 \\ 
&= &\int_0^c \int_0^c \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_1 \right) \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1\\ 
& +& 
 \int_0^c \int_{c-y_1}^\infty  a\exp\left(-b(y_1 +y_2)\right)  \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_1 \right) \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1 \\ 
&+&  \int_c^\infty \int_{0}^\infty  a\exp\left(-b y_1\right) a\exp\left(-b(y_1 +y_2)\right)  \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_1 \right) \beta \exp\left(- \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1.
\end{eqnarray}
Is the above derivation correct?

CCDF $= Pr\left\{Z > z \right\} =$ ?

Please note that if explicit expressions are difficult to derive, I need to at least write these expressions as integrals function of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\beta$; as done for $E\left\{Z\right\}$.

Comment: You need the distribution of $Z$ to make any expectation statements. Which starts by knowing the distribution of $Y=Y_1+Y_2$ which only exist if the support of $Y_1$  or $Y_2$ is bounded above by, say, $k$. In that case, $Y$ has pdf  $k\beta f(y_1)$ as a convolution.

Comment: Your derivation is wrong because you are assuming that $Z$ has the pdf $f(y_1)f(y_2)$ which is not true.

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha I have edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: The approach is correct, but the integral breaks into *four* parts, not three.  You will have an easier time by using a more abstract notation at the outset, because many of the resulting univariate integrals will be directly computed by the CDF $F(y)$.

Comment: @whuber I am only getting 3 parts: (1) $y_1<c$ and $y_1+y_2<c$, (2) $y_1<c$ and $y_1+y_2>c$, (3) $y_1>c$ and $y_1+y_2>c$. If I am not mistaken, the fourth part is $= 0$ since $y_1 >c$ and $y_1+y_2<c$ cannot happen. Do you have any idea on how to calculate CCDF(Z)?

Comment: Thank you.  I must be confused by your notation.  What could "$p(Y_1+Y_2\mid Y_1)$" possibly mean? You have given us a *function* $p$ but suddenly you change its notation without explaining what that change might mean.  Clearly $p$ is not always a probability: if $a$ is sufficiently large, it will exceed $1$.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry, I forgot to mention that $c=\frac{\log(a)}{b}$.

Comment: That's useful, but it still doesn't help us make  sense of your notation.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry but would you please tell me which one? $p(s)$ is a probability.

Comment: Although you *claim* $p$ is a probability, you do not explain what it might be the probability of (what's the event?  what's the sample space?) and you define it solely as a function.  That does not make it possible to interpret your subsequent notation with any confidence.  Since it's intended to be a probability, please tell us what it's the probability of.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the question. I hope things are clearer now. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I am curious what kind of problem/situation led to this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Starting point**

$$z = p(y_1)p(y_1+y_2)$$
$$y_1 \sim f(y)$$
$$y_2 \sim f(y)$$
\begin{equation}
p(s) = \begin{cases}  a \exp\left( - b s \right),    & \text{for $s \ge c$}    \\ 1,  & \text{for $0 < s < c $}    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
$$f(y) = \beta \exp\left(- \beta y\right),\beta>0$$
with $c=\log(a)/b$.

---

$\mathbf{E(Z)}$

Then

$$E(Z) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty p(y_1)p(y_1+y_2) f(y_1)f(y_2) dy_1 dy_2$$

*but it should be split into different integrals* (Whuber was right that you are missing a piece). You have the line  $y_1>c$ and $y_1+y_2>c$ giving you

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E} \left\{Z\right\} 
&= & \beta^2 \int_0^c \int_0^{c-y_1} \exp\left(- \beta y_1 - \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1\\ 
& +& a \beta^2 \int_0^c \int_{c-y_1}^\infty  \exp\left(-b\left(y_1 +y_2\right)- \beta y_1 - \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1 \\ 
&+&  a^2 \beta^2 \int_c^\infty \int_{0}^\infty  \exp\left(-b y_1-b(y_1 +y_2)- \beta y_1 - \beta y_2 \right)  dy_2 dy_1
\end{eqnarray}

The explicit expression is not difficult to derive from here, yet it is very cumbersome. Possibly certain simplifications are possible when you plug-in the value for $c$ in the final (integrated) expression.

---

$\mathbf{P(Z>z)}$

$z = p(y_1)p(y_1+y_2) = \begin{cases}
a^2  \exp\left( - 2b y_1 - b y_2 \right),    & \text{for $y_1 \ge c$}  \\
a  \exp\left( - b y_1 - b y_2 \right),    & \text{for $y_1 < c$ and $y_2 \ge c-y_1$}  \\
 1,  & \text{for $y_1 < c$ and $y_2 < c-y_1$}    \end{cases} $

Then you need to integrate $\int\int f(y_1)f(y_2) d y_1 d y_2$ in the region where $Z>z$ by applying the appropriate boundaries:

$$\begin{array}\\
1: \qquad &- b y_1 - b y_2 > \log(z/a)\\
2: \qquad &- 2b y_1 - b y_2 > \log(z/a^2)
\end{array}$$

This requires you, again, to split up the integral.

See also the below image for the level of $z$ as a function of $y_1$ and $y_2$. You will need to integrate using the two before mentioned borders, but it is a bit nasty to write it out in full so I will leave it here with the image:

[image: z as function of y1 and y2]

Comment: In the expression of $E\{Z\}$ you provide, I think that the integral limits in the first line should be as follows: $\int_0^c \int_0^c$. This corresponds to the case: $y_1<c$ and $y_1+y_2<c$, so $y_2<c-y_1<c$. As for $y_1 >c$ and $y_1+y_2>c$, it is represented in the third line. If my observations are correct, then the expression of $E\{Z\}$ that I provide is correct (?).

Comment: Regarding $P\{ Z>z\}$, I am sorry but I am not sure I have understood. Would you please elaborate a bit more, or at least write $P\{ Z>z\}$ as a function of some integrals ?

Comment: You mean: the case $y_1<c$ and $y_1+y_2<c$ yields $y_2<c-y_1$ ? But in this case, in the first line there should be $\int_0^c \int_0^{c-y_1}$ and not $\int_0^c \int_0^{y_1}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Regarding the CCDF, would you please explain why we need: $\int \int f(y_1) f(y_2)  dy_1 dy_2$ ?

Comment: I am going to award you the bounty. But please, I need the integral bounds; I don't know how to split the integral for the CCDF expression you  provide.

Comment: I have added an image that provides you with some help to define the integral limits. It is a bit nasty work so I haven't written it out in full but you should get something like $$\int_{y_1=0}^{y_1=c} \int_{y_2=\mu_1}^{y_2=\infty} f(y_1)f(y_2) dy_2 d 1_2 + \int_{y_1=c}^{y_1=\infty} \int_{y_2=\mu_2}^{y_2=\infty} f(y_1)f(y_2) d y_2 d y_1$$

where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the (linear) boundaries for $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that z=Z.